# While using a navgiation drawer and a viewpager: how to swipe another full screen fragment over/instead of the others

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

The App uses a Navigation Drawer and a Viewpager (with each tab contains a fragment).

From the actionbar I would like to show an extra full screen fragment instead of the other fragments. This fragment could contain e.g. the user settings.

And ...

It would be very nice to use the top-left "<" back button of the navigation drawer to leave the new fragment and show the viewpager with the tabs again.

The most beautiful option would be the new fragment pushing the other fragments aside.

I don't want to start a new Activity, as I am working with pleasure with Fragements in all my Apps.

The DialogFragment is not suitable (as I tried).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to do is replace the fragment:

```
getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, new Fragment())
    .addToBackStack("TAG")
    .commit();
```

You can use one of the various methods available to animate this, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html

Disable the nav drawer and you should get a back button, if not you can call (I think you should have already done this to setup the nav drawer):

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

You'll need to handle the back button press by implementing `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // Go back
            break;
    }
}
```

You'll probably need to handle the hardware back button in your activity too.